# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^\frac{1}{n} = x$ and $a_n \neq 0$ imply $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = x$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^\frac{1}{n} = x$. However, does $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^\frac{1}{n} = x$ and $a_n \neq 0$ imply $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = x$? I can't seem to find a counterexample nor do I know how to prove that it is true. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Comparison) mentions an example where ratio test is inconclusive but root test works. It is obtained by "doubling" a convergent series, i.e., every term is taken twice. (But I am sure that other interesting examples are also possible. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?q=stronger+ratio+root+test+series) is a bunch of results from Google Books where some other examples could be found.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a_n = (-1)^n$. then $|a_n|^{1/n} = 1 \to 1 = x$. However

$$ \frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{ (-1)^{n+1}}{(-1)^n} = -1 \to -1 \neq x$$

Comment: Hi just wondering, what if a_n are all positive, can counterexample still be found?